# Do we always need to to use CacheManager?

Tags: java, ehcache

I noticed that according to the documentation, to create a Cache, you have to instantiate or obtain a CacheManager and add the Cache to it.

```
singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
Cache memoryOnlyCache = new Cache("testCache", 5000, false, false, 5, 2);
singletonManager.addCache(memoryOnlyCache);
Cache test = singletonManager.getCache("testCache");
```

However, the following code seems to be working

```
public class MyCache {

    private static Cache cache = null;

    ...

    private MyCache() {
        cache = new Cache(cacheName, 200, MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LFU, false, null, false, timeToLiveSeconds, 0L, false, 0, null);
        cache.initialise();
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1/ Why is this working? I verified I can add or remove entries, and the cache is expired.

2/ If this would work, but is not the proper way to implement it, why initialise is public?. It could have default access.

Answer (score 2):

Ehcache 2.x requires a `CacheManager` in order to provide caches. This is the documented and recommended way of using caches. A `Cache` not linked to a `CacheManager` may cause all sorts of problems, especially for more advanced features.

Some of the features that are the responsibility of a `CacheManager`:

- Repository of `Cache`s
- `Cache` initialization

  - Includes some bi-directional linking that cache and its configuration assumes are properly set
- SizeOf engine provider for on heap byte sizing
- Transaction manager provider
- Statistics executor provider
- ARC pooling provider

The reason for being able to construct and initialise a `Cache` resides in historical reasons (API, `Cache` being a class and not an interface) and the will to preserve backwards compatibility.

Ehcache 3.x will come with the concept of *user managed* caches, that is caches that are not linked to a `CacheManager`. They will be well suited for use cases where you only need put/get/evict/expiry features.

Comment: When using multiple caches across the nodes, CacheManagers allows to configure CacheManagerPeerListeners, CacheManagerPeerProviders etc which are useful in propagating any cache or cache entry changes to ensure they are all in sync or prevent data staleness. Real time scenario - Using Ehcache as hibernate second level cache deployed across multiple nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Louis. I agree this is what the ehCache 2.x documentation states. What I would like to understand is what are the **CacheManager** responsabilities.  Would it be possible to name a few of the problems? (i.e. eviction, disk overflow, persistence, ...)

Comment: Listed some of the responsibilities